# htaccess - rewrite url not working at all

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using Apache on CentOS 6 and in my htaccess I have this line of code to rewrite url into something more reader friendly

```
RewriteRule ^destinations/(.*)$ destinations.php?destId=$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

It's supposed to `rewrite example.com/destinations/florida` to `example.com/destinations.php?destId=florida`

On my page destinations.php I don't get any output from

```
echo $_GET['destId'];
```

I could've sworn it was working properly a few days back, but not anymore. First off, I added `R=301` to see the url change in the browser but id doesn't. I've checked a hundred times but there's no syntax error here. Here's another one which isn't working either

```
RewriteRule ^tours/?(.*)$ tour-listing.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]
```

While this one does work

```
RewriteRule ^bnb-in-(.*)$ hotel-search.php?t=bnb&s=$1 [NC,L]
```

They're all in one file. And all of them work on localhost. I've modified apache's httpd.conf file recently to install SSL certificates so my guess is something went wrong there. Here's that code:

```
<VirtualHost ser.ver.ip.addr:80>
    ServerName www.example.in
        ServerAlias example.in
    Redirect "/" "https://example.in/"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost ser.ver.ip.addr:443>
        ServerName example.in:443
        ServerAlias www.example.in
        DocumentRoot /home/veek/public_html
       SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/certfile.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/keyfile.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/intermediate.pem
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES2$
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on

        <Directory /home/veek/public_html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.in
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.in combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.in-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
         UserDir enabled veek
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup veek veek
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup veek veek
        </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid veek veek
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
        #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
        AssignUserID veek veek
    </IfModule>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/veek/public_html/cgi-bin/

</VirtualHost>
```

Here's the complete htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule /$ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^destinations/(.*)$ destinations.php?destId=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^tours/(.*)$ tour-listing.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tour/(.*)$ tour.php?tourId=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^hotels-in-(.*)$ hotel-search.php?s=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^hotels hotel-search.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^hotel/(.*)$ hotel-details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^bnb-in-(.*)$ hotel-search.php?t=bnb&s=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^bnb hotel-search.php?t=bnb [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^camps-in-(.*)$ hotel-search.php?t=camps&s=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^camps hotel-search.php?t=camps [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^thank-you message.php?id=1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^404 message.php?id=2 [NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `isn't working` means it is redirecting but `destId` is blank, or it is not redirecting at all?

Comment: Well the url doesn't changes in the browser and I don't get anything in `destId` so I'm not sure what's hapening. It seems that it doesn't match at all

Comment: If you have `R=301` and URL does not change, then the RewriteRule is not applied. Some rules work, so basic setup is ok; then either the Pattern is not matched (which is trivial, so let's eliminate that) or the rule is never reached. For that to investigate, we need to see all of`.htaccess`

Comment: I've used `isset($_GET['destId'])` and it doesn't gets triggered. So the url was not appended by `destId` I guess

Comment: I've edited my question to include the complete htaccess file

Comment: It is a bit strange. Are there perhaps any other `.conf` files that might influence rewriting?

Comment: Not that I know of. The only conf file I modified has been included above

Comment: It's definitely the apache config, I replaced the whole block with the backup I had. This was before I made any changes to it and the links work. I'll debug further to find the specific problem. I'll put my money on `<Directory>` block

Comment: I was right, It was the line `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews` in the `Directory` block of my httpd.conf file. Would someone write an answer explaining the cause?